# Android Studio app not appearing in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Cleared the project and build my app, which is using Ionic, Capacitor and Vue3.js. According to the logs, the build completes without errors. But the app does not appear in the emulator.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cash.dat.mobile">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="cash.dat.mobile.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should select an emulator and launch it, not only launching an emulator

Comment: @Dewerro what do you mean? I'm new to Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you should select your emulator on a top bar, and click on green triangle to launch app. App will install automatically.
[image]

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I didn't realize the play button in that tool bar was different from the play button in the device manager. On another note, if the app isn't opening, do you have any suggestions for debugging?

Comment: for debugging you can click on a green "bug" button, then see debug logcat in the bottom of android studio

Comment: When I use the debugger, it just opens and closes the app

Comment: I think the problem is in the app. Android studio always sends stacktrace, look here: https://imgur.com/2RjFWfW

Comment: Not getting any issues: https://imgur.com/a/AM3hD1J

Comment: I think you selected your actual device, not emulator. Try to launch on emulator.

Comment: I rebuilt the project, launched device and then the app. Now errors are logging under run tab. Thanks for the help!

Comment: by the way, you don't need to build project and launch it. When you click on green triangle it will build and update your app